# Get title back after searchBar isHidden in UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a `searchBar` that is displayed in the `UINavigationBar` when a `searchButton` is pressed. After the search is done or the user cancels the search, I want the `title` to get back in the `UINavigationBar` How can I get it back?

The searchBar is shown like this:

```swift
@IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if searchBar.isHidden == true {
        searchBar.isHidden = false
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar
        searchActive = true
    } else if searchBar.isHidden == false {
        searchBar.isHidden = true
        searchActive = false
        //Show title again
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set titleView to nil and assign navigation item title back.

Comment: @LukaCefarin That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

just do this, and then there's no messing about with viewcontroller's set title method

```
@IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if searchBar.isHidden == true {
            searchBar.isHidden = false
            self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar
            searchActive = true
        } else if searchBar.isHidden == false {
            searchBar.isHidden = true
            searchActive = false
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "My Title"
            label.textColor = .red
            self.navigationItem.titleView = label
        }
    }
```